# How to deal correctly with similar views in storyboard, that have similar controllers without duplication of the code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have 2 views in the storyboard (xcode, swift), that have the same main element, but completely different navigation elements. One view is shown just after the registration and the second one is a part of app settings.

Here is how the pages look like:

- [Onboarding select books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2AK.png)
- [select books in the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOuC9.png)

What my programmer did: 2 separate views with copied&pasted elements and also separate controllers (with duplicated functions, 400 lines of code are copy&pasted!)

What is the correct way to do it in Xcode?

Comment: My mistake, I did put screenshots from Android. The problem we have appears in the XCode. I did upload new screenshots.

Comment: Okay, that explains why. Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with iOS anymore. Good luck with your question!

Comment: You can Make that View as an XIB and then you can reuse it every where. you just need to code in your single view.

Comment: Add that view xib as a sub view to your viewController where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique UIViewController that will handle the "list" thing, and embed it in 2 different other UIViewController that will just handle the different navigation. You can use the "containerView" element in the storyboard. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html